# Add content depending on page loaded

Tags: wp-query

I would like to add some code depending on which page the users are.

```
  <?php 
$arr = array(2506, 2516,2512,2513,2509,2515,2510,2508,2514,2511,2507);
if (in_array(the_ID(),$arr)){
    if ($_SESSION['logged'] != 'true'){
        echo '<script>document.location.href="./connexion";</script>'; //Not logged so good bye !
    }
} 
?>
```

I know my that it's not quite accurate but can you check it out ?

Any clue on how to make this ?

Comment: You've posted your *attempted implementation*, but haven't really identified what *exactly* you're trying to accomplish. From your code, I *assume* you're trying to identify when you're on a given set of pages, by Page ID?

Comment: I have modified it so it could be easier to understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to output content conditionally, depending on whether you are on a given set of static pages, by Page ID, you can simply wrap your code in an [**`is_page()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) conditional.

To determine if the current user is logged in, you can use the [**`is_user_logged_in()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) conditional.

For example

```
// Array of Page IDs
$page_ids = array( 2506,2516,2512,2513,2509,2515,2510,2508,2514,2511,2507 );

// If the current context is a static page with one of the above IDs
// and the current user is logged in
if ( is_page( $page_ids ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // This is one of our pages
    // Do something
}
```

Or for the case in which the current user is *not* logged in:

```
// Array of Page IDs
$page_ids = array( 2506,2516,2512,2513,2509,2515,2510,2508,2514,2511,2507 );

// If the current context is a static page with one of the above IDs
// and the current user is NOT logged in
if ( is_page( $page_ids ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // This is one of our pages
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the user login from wordpress unfortunately that why I'm using that session. But the code is great. Thanks